# Center four images in css

Tags: html, css, image

Basically I want to center within a div tag with a class name container 4 pictures looking like a windows. Here is my code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class = "arriba">
      <img class = "pic" src="img/il00.jpg">
      <img class="pic" src="img/web00.png">
  </div>
  <div class="abajo">
      <img class="pic" src="img/logo.jpg">
      <img class="pic" src="img/w.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my css

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    left: 50%;
    
}
img.pic{
    padding: 5px;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this css

> `.container > *{ margin : auto }`

or yo can see at this link https://jsfiddle.net/eq7p391a/

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `justify-content: center` in `container`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32zu0cLs/2/)

```
.container{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    width:100%;    
}
```